# Importing application image from local docker registry

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, s2i

I have a docker application image created using [s2i](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) implementation. I was able to import it in the server(OpenShift) but when I create a project using this image, it does not detect any image. I am guessing that I have imported a whole application image but not an image stream? I'm using [OpenShift Cli](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html) tool to import the image.

The docker application image is set up from my local.

I'm new to this set up but if anyone who have related experience to this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you import it into the server (OpenShift)? What commands are you running? If you used ``oc import-image`` to pull it in from an external image registry, it would create an image stream.

Comment: BTW, if you are using an S2I builder to build the application image, why not just build it in OpenShift to begin with? What is the S2I builder you are using?

Comment: We are using a custom s2i (universityofadelaide/s2i-shepherd-drupal). We cannot find any documentation on how to push from s2i to the openshift registry. The only thing close to this is using oc import-image.